# Lookup Each item from a list to items from List2. If there's a match return such value, if not delete the entire row

Tags: python, iteration

I have two lists that were created from columns from two different dataframes. The two dataframes have the following structure:

```
In [73][dev]: cw.shape                                                 
Out[73]: (4666, 13)

In [74][dev]: ml.shape                                                 
Out[74]: (815, 5)
```

and the two lists are identifier objects intended to match data from one dataframe with another. My intention is conceptually equivalent to a vlookup in Excel, which is to look up whether an item from list ID is in list ID2, and if so, returns the appropriate 'class1' value from the second list into this new "Class" that I've created. If the "vlookup" (pardon my Excel reference here but hopefully you catch my drift) doesn't find the relevant value, the drop all rows.

```
import pandas as pd

cw = pd.read_excel("abc.xlsx")  
ml = pd.read_excel("xyz.xlsx")

ID = cw['Identifier'] 
cw["Class"] = "" 
asc = cw["Class"]

ID2 = ml['num'] 
bac = ml['class1'] 

for item in ID:
    if item in ID2:
        asc[item] = bac[item]
    else:
        cw.drop(cw.index, inplace = True)
```

Unfortunately the pasted script drops all rows in cw, rendering it a blank dataframe. Not what I intended. Again, what I'm targeting for here is to remove rows that don't get a match between two ID identifiers, and return class1 values for those rows with matching IDs into this new Class column that I've just created.

```
In [76][dev]: cw.shape                                                                                                                                   
Out[76]: (0, 13)
```

I hope I've made this clear. I suspect I didn't setup the if statement correctly but not sure. Thank you very much for helping a beginner here.

Comment: In the `else`, you're not using `item`, so you're doing some global operation instead. I'm guessing that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks joanis. I don't think that's the problem as I tried replacing the cw.drop() with a print('Not found'). It seems to print thousands of lines of "Not found" after the reiteration of the loop. So my guess is I messed up setting up the if statement but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler and more straight forward solution by using pandas merge.

```
# Merge with master list 
cw_ac = pd.merge(cw, ml, on='cusip', how='inner')
```

This acts like an inner join in SQL based on the identifier and remove non-matching IDs.